# How to support API calls to use a Promise or Callbacks with Standard Promises, no defers or external Promise Library?

Tags: javascript, api, callback, promise, es6-promise

I'm wondering how to support `Promise`'s and Callbacks in an API. So far I've read through a few articles to try to implement however all these articles use deferred or a third party Promise library that has Deferred's. I want to use Native ES Promises. I wanted to know how to implement something like this. Please do not reference Promisify or any third party library as I actually want to implement this. The function signature is like the following:

```
function (callback) {
  if (callback) {
    // wrap callback and return Promise thats thenable
  }
  // return a Promise thats thenable
}
```

This is something I had in my head for how something should go but I'm not sure how to implement. If you have experience or know how to do this please reply as I'd like to learn.

Comment: yes, that's how you'd do it

Comment: Can you provide further context?

Comment: Are you trying to implement a library that supports either promises or callbacks?  Or are you just trying to implement your library with promises?  If it's the former, then `jQuery.ajax()` is an example of an API that can be used with either a promise or a callback.  You can look at that.  It returns a promise, but accepts an optional callback.  If the callback is passed, it will be called.  In both cases, the promise will resolve/reject.

Comment: https://github.com/metagrover/ES6-for-humans#17-promises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further context to Question, not entirely certain what expected result is from function other than "thenable".

The simplest approach would be to utilize `Promise.resolve()` or `Promise.reject()`; though you could also use `Promise.all()`, `Promise.race()` or `new Promise()` constructor to return a "thenable".

```js
function fn(callback) {
  if (callback) {
    // wrap callback and return Promise thats thenable
    return Promise.resolve(callback())
  }
  // return a Promise thats thenable
  return Promise.resolve()
}

fn().then(function(data) {
  console.log("no callback passed:", data); // `data` : `undefined`
})

fn(function() {return 123})
.then(function(data) {
  console.log("callback passed:", data); // `data`: `123`
})
```

Comment: I chose this solution because It was the simplest approach

Comment: @guyforlowbro - Odd because I don't see any async operations in this scheme.  The whole point of using promises is to support async operations.  If your API is not async operations, then why use promises at all?  Maybe your question was just never clear about what you are trying to accomplish.  I notice you never answered the comments where people asked you what you were trying to do.  Why is that?

Comment: @jfriend00 _"Odd because I don't see any async operations in this scheme."_? Asynchronous operations can be used within the pattern at Answer. What is purpose of asking OP about _"the comments where people asked you what you were trying to do"_ here? Perhaps post comments to OP as to those under original Question, where comments were made?

Comment: I addressed my previous comment directly to the OP and put it here because the main part was about this answer.  It is unclear to me where async operations go in your above pattern.  I guess I just never understood what the OP wanted.  Unclear question.  Unresponsive OP.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, original Question is not entirely clear as to context. Not certain exactly how OP will use pattern, though asynchronous operations can be handled by pattern, as indicated by possible usage of `Promise.all()`, `Promise.race()` or `new Promise(fn)` constructor. Did not create scenarios in Answer, to avoid confusion, as OP appeared to seek a basic approach. Even frequent viewers of SO promise Questions/Answers may be inspired to ask you how each line of your posted approaches actually function. You cannot force a user to accept a particularly detailed Answer.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to do like `jQuery.ajax()` does and you always return a promise and, if the optional callback is present, then you call it too.

Here's one idea for that when your internal async operation does not use promises:

```
function myAPIxxx(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    callback = callback || function() {};
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        someAsyncOperation(arg1, arg2, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                callback(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
                callback(null, data);
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Since much of this is boilerplate, you could create a common wrapper that would do this for all your API functions.

If your internal operations are all using promises, then it's a little easier.

```
function myAPIxxx(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    callback = callback || function() {};
    return someAsyncOperation(arg1, arg2).then(callback.bind(null, null), callback);
}
```

---

If you already have a callback-based API that follows the node.js async callback calling convention, then you could simply call a promisify function on each of your API calls to create a new promise-based interface.  I don't really understand why you suggest not mentioning promisify because if you already have a callback-based API and you want to support both, using a promisify function on each of your API calls is the cleanest, most foolproof way to add a promise-based interface.

If you're curious, here's a promisify function that accepts your existing callback API function and returns a new promise-based function:

```
function promisify(fn, obj) {
    if (typeof fn !== "function") {
        throw new Error("fn argument to promisify() must be function");
    }
    // obj is optional and may be undefined
    // if present, it will be used as context to call fn as in obj.fn()
    return function(/* args */) {
        // make copy of arguments object into a real array in a way that
        // does not prevent interpreter optimizations
        var args = new Array(arguments.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            args[i] = arguments[i];
        }
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            // add our callback function at the end of the args list
            var resultMany;
            args.push(function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    // if 0 or 1 result, then just return it as a simple value
                    if (arguments.length <= 2) {
                        resolve(result);
                    } else {
                        // if more than one result came with the callback function, 
                        // then put it into an array so we can resolve with a single value (the array of results)
                        // skip the first argument which is the err value
                        resultMany = new Array(arguments.length - 1);
                        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {
                            resultMany[i] = arguments[i + 1];
                        }
                        resolve(resultMany);
                    }
                }
            });
            // call original function with our callback as last argument
            fn.apply(obj, args);
        });
    }
}
```

So, if you had a function called `myAPIxxx()` that was callback based, you could create a new one that was promise-based like this:

```
var myAPIxxxAsync = promisify(myAPIxxx);
```

If all your APIs are properties on a single object, you could just loop over the API and create a new promisified version of the existing API with one loop.

And, here's a function that would loop over an API object and create promisified versions of each with a different suffix on them:

```
function promisfyObj(obj, suffix) {
    var asyncName, method, promiseSuffix, type = typeof obj;
    var hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
    if (!(type === "function" || type === "object")) {
        throw new Error("first argument to promisifyObj() must be function or object");
    }
    if (suffix && typeof suffix !== "string") {
        throw new Error("second argument to promisifyObj() must be a string or not present at all");        
    }
    promiseSuffix = suffix ? suffix : "Async";
    for (method in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[method] === "function" && hasOwn.call(obj, method)) {
            asyncName = method + promiseSuffix;
            if (!(asyncName in obj)) {
                obj[asyncName] = promisify(obj[method], obj);
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

So, if all your API functions were on a common object such as `myAPI.someFunc()`, then you could add promisified versions of every API like this:

```
promisifyObj(myAPI);
```

Comment: Question is indeed unclear, but promisification of a function is the only thing that makes any sense. This should be the selected answer.

Comment: if `obj` is optional, then it needs some safety, eg. `obj = obj || this` in the inner function?

Comment: Also, line count (and apparent complexity) comes down considerably if you are prepared to use `Array.prototype.slice.call()` (twice).

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - The only thing `obj` is used for in the `promisify()` function is `fn.apply(obj, args)`.  If it's null or undefined that's fine.  I don't intend to make up a dummy object there.  Is there some reason you think it needs to be an actual object?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - It's purposely not using `Array.prototype.slice.call()` because that prevents some interpreter optimizations with the function arguments (the comments in the code provide an explanation for why it is the way it is).

Comment: Do you have a reference on those optimisation issues please?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - Reference here: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#32-leaking-arguments.  Since this type of code gets proxied into every single API that it is promisifying, it seems worth it to use a few extra lines of code to enable max optimization (at least that was my thinking).  And, some measurements here: http://bahmutov.calepin.co/detecting-function-optimizations-in-v8.html

Answer (score 0):

Promises in ES2015 are very easy to use

```js
var everyThingIsOk = true;

// here you are defining native ES2015 promise with callback function which is your async operation;
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    if(everyThingIsOk){ // if task has done you should call resolve function with data as parameter;
        resolve("this async task has been successfully done");
    }
    else{ // if not you should return reject function with reason that can help you;
        reject("there were some errors during execution or in logic");
    }
})

promise.then(function(result){ // method resolve will call callback of then
    alert(result)
})
.catch(function(error){ // method reject will call callback of catch
    alert(error)
})
```

so for callback you need methods `resolve` and `reject`;
and you can do so

`Promise.resolve(callback)` and `Promise.reject(callback)`

and return these statements from your function

Comment: I know how to use a promise not sure about how to support Promise and Callback. This is why I didn't chose this.